# Google analytics showing spam event instead of my events

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I have integrated analytics in my android app, for monitoring the app. I have sent few events. But the analytics web interface is not showing those events instead it is showing some spam event like : to use this feature visit: EVENT-TRACKING.COM.

Also when I was checking with "Real Time -> Event" feature on web interface, the event that I wanted was there at the top of Web Interface, but after some time (10 - 12 hours) none of the my events appeared there. Only the spam event was there. How do I see my events ? is there any way ?

Here is my code at android site :

```
// Build and send an Event.
        MyApp.getDefaultTracker().send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                .setCategory(category)
                .setAction(action)
                .setLabel(label)
                .setValue(tvalue)
                .build());
```

Here is image of analytics web interface :

[image]

I am able to get the Exceptions related with my app on analytics. But not the events.

Comment: How does your code and gtm look?

Comment: @JohanShogun I have updated question, but I think android site code is ok, cause I was able to see the 'Event' in "Real Time" tab at web interface, but when I looked analytics dashboard in morning nothing was there except the spam event.

Comment: After you've seen an event in real time it can take up to 24 hours before it shows in your statistics

Comment: @JohnShogun its been more than 30 hrs, but none of the my events on web interface, seems like something went wrong. Only spam event showing.

Comment: How does the data in your events look? Exactly how are you doing this? :) if there is something wrong with the event Google analytics sometimes ignores them. Also if this is a new account there is a time limit before its activated, I think 48 hours, but if you already waited 30 from your events being sent and saw them in real time you should already have passed that time

Comment: For category, action and label there are custom strings and for value its 1l, that's all, is it required to define custom categories at web dashboard ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to define custom categories, do you do anything special with your session management?

Comment: I have nothing special with session.

Comment: Hmmmm.... What do your strings look like for action category etc? Also make sure you select the correct dates in the google analytics web view.

Comment: Strings are all caps, like for category : "XYZ_CATEGORY", for action "XYZ_ACTION" so on.

Comment: Ok was thinking they could have been too long, see here for what the values can be https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#eventValue